# How does rescuing work?

Tags: pokemon-mystery-dungeon, pokemon-super-mystery-dungeon

I got a "pro tip" in my game that says that if I fainted in a dungeon, I can give a code to other players to come rescue me. How does this process work? What do I get out of it? Will it revive me in the place I fainted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you supply another player with the code, they go through your dungeon getting to the floor you died and find you. Once they do that you've been saved and can continue your dungeon from the floor and spot you died. I know in previous games when they saved you they could also grant you items to help you on your travels. I'm not 100% sure if that stayed in the game though.

If your working by code then yes the rescuer gets a code that you type in. If you do it over the internet, then once your saved it updates your game and allows you to continue. The code is for offline play, it was used for the original game on GBA/DS

Comment: How does your game know that you've been saved? Does your rescuer have to send you another code or is it done through the internet?

Comment: If your working by code then yes the rescuer gets a code that you type in. If you do it over the internet, then once your saved it updates your game and allows you to continue. The code is for offline play, it was used for the original game on GBA/DS